# Throttler blocking others IPs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, throttling

I have a nestjs application that uses throttler to limit the number of requests the application can receive before returning 429.

As it says in the documentation, it blocks by IP: [npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/throttler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/throttler)

However, I'm using the heroku.loader addon to simulate many users accessing the endpoint.

My test was to generate 100 connections per second for 30 seconds, and in the meantime I would access my api through my browser.

The problem is that in my browser I received a 429 from the throttler even though I made only 1 request. Is it normal for throttler to block other IPs? I checked the logs, and the IP of each fake user that the loader creates, has a different IP. Shouldn't block mine

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/security/rate-limiting#proxies see that adding `app.set('trust proxy', true)` would fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best solution but, you can by req.header.fingerprint that your client should send random with every request header (implementation: when the user visits the front-end site, fingerprint should be generated and saved to cookies or localStorage if there is any in cookies). If there is any better solution, please inform me :)

```js
// throttler-behind-proxy.guard.ts
@Injectable()
export class ThrottlerBehindProxyGuard extends ThrottlerGuard {
  protected async getTracker(req: Record<string, any>): Promise<string> {
    const ip = req.ips.length ? req.ips[0] : req.ip;
    const fingerprint = req?.headers?.fingerprint;
    return ip + fingerprint;
  }
}
```